# Finding patterns in a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, tuples

I have a matrix in which I want to find the largest pattern available. For that, I'm using numpy's argwhere method.

```
color = 10
solutions = np.argwhere(matrix==color)
```

When I print solutions I get all the indexes where the color exists. Now I want to find a pattern i.e, indexes that are adjacent to each other. I'm not sure if im going in the right direction but if yes then kindly help me out.

Comment: This is an interesting question, however, you need to show some effort: what have you tried so far. Please provide code *and* (not *or*) examples.

Comment: I ended up using re. re.sub("[^0-9]", "", str(mylist[i]) to get the coordinates.